# Arrays from feature collections in Google Earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, array

I need to convert a Feature Collection containing only numeric data to a 2D matrix. I have written the following code however it gives `matA` as a list of arrays despite explicit type conversion, here `table` is my feature collection and `data` is the list of properties I need to extract into the matrix

```js
// list of data to extract from FC
var data=ee.List(['bio01','bio02','bio03','bio04','bio05','bio06','bio07',
              'bio08','bio09','bio10','bio11','bio12','bio13','bio14',            
       'bio15','bio16','bio17','bio18','bio19','dem','tmax','tmin','prec']);

//data becomes the list from which the user wants to remove the ones he doesn't need

var tableArray=table.toList(200,0)  // list of features

var tableList=ee.List(tableArray.map(function(element){
  var feat=ee.Feature(element)  
  var array=feat.toArray(data)  //feature to array
  return ee.List(array) //array to list 
}))

// array needs all elements of list only not array inside list so we change feature to list

var matA=ee.Array(tableList)

print(matA)
```

The error I am getting is:

```js
Array (Error)
Array: Unrecognized type, may only use numbers or lists, found type Array.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works to convert feature collection to arrays

```
var tableList = table.toList(200).map(function(element) {
  return ee.Feature(element).toArray(data)
})

var matA = ee.Array.cat(tableList, 1)
```